# Reusing Angular component with different input

Tags: html, angular, typescript, three.js

I have ran into a strange problem that I'm not really sure where to begin investigating of what could cause it. I'm currently using a library, angular-stl-model-viewer that uses Three.js. I call a component that renders a 3D model. However, when I call the component again and add a different file both components have both parts even though each component was assigned one different part file.

Ex.

```
  <div class="row">
    <stl-model-viewer stlModel="model/teapot"
                      class="col-5"></stl-model-viewer>
    <span class="col-2"></span>
    <stl-model-viewer stlModel="model/other"
                      class="col-5"></stl-model-viewer>
  </div>
```

2 different components first should just be a teapot with part in the middle

Image of both parts in both components
[image]

I feel like the component is being referenced as one even though it's there twice. Is there a way to make each invoke of the component unique and separate? Also I understand this may have been asked before but didn't really know what word or phrase to search. Sorry about this and thanks for the help.

Comment: This is likely a bug in the library you’re using and not angular itself. I’d start there. Component in angular are always “unique and separate”

Answer (score 0):

Temporary fix might be :-

```
<stl-model-viewer *ngIf="showModel" stlModel="model/teapot"
```

For eg:- if you are changing filename in a method :-

```
changeFileName() {
   this.showModel = false;
   //file Name Changing Code Here
   setTimeout(()=>{this.showModel=true});
}
```

As you won't get a fix soon. One use posted same question 26 days ago :-

https://github.com/tevim/angular-stl-model-viewer/issues/389#issue-605311429